# Real $2\pi$ periodic functions

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f$ is continuous (with period $2\pi$). 
In book write the following: "we may regard the $2\pi$ periodic functions on $\mathbb{R^1}$ as functions on the unit circle $T$, by means of the mapping $x\mapsto e^{ix}$."

Can anyone expalin it to me please?

Answer (score 0):

I think that above means the following:

You have function $f(x)\in C^{2\pi}$ defined on $\mathbb{R}^1$. You must to make it a periodic function on $\mathbb{T}=\{z\in \mathbb{C}: |z|=1\}.$ We can take segment $[0,2\pi]$ and transform $t\mapsto e^{it}$ translates it to unit circle. Right?

For example: Let $f(x)=\sin x$. We know that it's continuous function with period $2\pi$ defined on $\mathbb{R}^1$. Then $f(e^{ix})=\sin x$.